# How to reimplement a class with sets instead of arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, functional-programming, set

I am trying to redevelop the Colony class I wrote for Conway's Game of Life with Sets instead of arrays but am having trouble doing so. Here's what I've got so far:
P.S. I am assuming a fixed Colony size of 20x20.

```
import Foundation
struct Array2DB {
    var values: [Int]
    var rows: Int
    var cols: Int
    init(rows: Int, cols: Int){
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        values = [Int](repeating: 0, count: (rows + 2) * (cols + 2) )
    }
    //allows uasge of the syntax [row, col] for get/set access
    subscript(row:Int, col: Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return values[getIndex(row, col)]
        }
        set(val) {
            values[getIndex(row, col)] = val
        }
    }
    //converts 2D indices to index in data (terminates if out of bounds)
    func getIndex(_ row: Int, _ col: Int) -> Int {
        assert((row >= -1) && (row <= rows), "row \(row) is out of bounds")
        assert((col >= -1) && (col <= cols), "col \(col) is out of bounds")
        return (row + 1) * cols + col + 1
    }
    var description: String {
        var desc = "Matrix:\n"
        for row in 0 ..< rows {
            for col in 0 ..< cols {
                desc += "  \(values[getIndex(row, col)])  "
            }
            desc += "\n"
        }
        return desc
    }
}
```

---

```
class Colony: CustomStringConvertible {
    let colony: Set = Array2DB[rows, cols, values]

    func setCellAlive(xCoor: Int, yCoor: Int) {
        colony[xCoor, yCoor] = 1
    }
    func setCellDead(xCoor:Int, yCoor: Int) {
        colony[xCoor, yCoor] = 0
    }
    func resetColony() {
        for i in 0..<colony.rows {
            for e in 0..<colony.cols {
                colony[i, e] = 0
            }
        }

    }
    var description: String {
        var desc = ""
        for i in 0..<colony.rows {
            for e in 0..<colony.cols {
                if colony[i, e] == 1 {
                    desc += "*"
                } else {
                    desc += "-"
                }
            }
            desc += "\n"
        }
        return desc
    }
    func isCellALive( xCoor: Int, yCoor: Int) -> Bool{
        return colony[xCoor, yCoor] == 1
    }
    func evolve() {
        var colonyUpdate: Array2DB = colony
        for i in 0..<colony.rows {
            for e in 0..<colony.cols {
                let cGen = rules(xCoor: i, yCoor: e)
                if ((cGen < 2) || (cGen > 3)) {
                    colonyUpdate[i, e] = 0
                } else if cGen == 3 {
                    colonyUpdate[i, e] = 1
                } else {
                    if colony[i, e] == 1 {
                        colonyUpdate[i, e] = 1
                    } else {
                        colonyUpdate[i, e] = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        colony = colonyUpdate
    }
}
```

I'm sure that I've implemented it wrong, but how would I turn the arrays to sets? I'm really confused and would appreciate any guidance or feedbac

Comment: `Set` in Swift cannot take two-dimension subscript like your `Array2DB`. How do you rewrite such code like `colony[xCoor, yCoor] = 1` ?

Comment: I'm developing the colony class with sets instead of arrays since the original code looked like this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ovDBW1ucnAPnpTh6Dju5zTWmc47gmon_KHYLE8mQWCU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: colony is of the type Array2D which is an array

Comment: You have not done much other than rewriting `var colony: Array2DB` to `let colony: Set = Array2DB[rows, cols, values]` which immediately causes compile error. **_colony is of the type Array2D which is an array_** Sure, it is in the original code, and in your goal what do you think it should be?

Comment: well at the moment, I'm getting rid of the array altogether and replacing it with a Cell struct with a set of alive cells. After, I'll edit the syntax and update my code to see if it runs...the goal is to have this running solely on sets.

Comment: Then you should better show your latest code using **`Cell` struct**, and clarify which part you think is difficult. Currently, your question just looks like asking _Do my homework for me_.

Comment: Why would you even want a `Set`? A `Set`'s elements are unique. So at the inner "column" level, only 3 possible sets would exist: `[dead]`, `[alive]`, `[alive, dead]`. Plus, the `Set` doesn't have a different ordering, so you wouldn't have rows and columns, you would just have senseless unordered groups of senseless entities

Answer (score 0):

Your data type `Array2DB` is not an `Array`. It is a `Struct` that *contains* an array. You can't assign an `Array2DB` to a variable that you've declared to be of type `Set`. It won't work.

You also can't use a `Set` as the storage for Conway's game of life. The Swift `Set` data type is an unordered collection. It is unsuitable to serve as the storage for the data in the game of life. You want an array, period.

Answer (score 0):

A very little help for you to show an example of using `Set` in Game of Life.

```
struct Cell: Hashable {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

class Colony: CustomStringConvertible {
    var aliveCells: Set = Set<Cell>()

    let numberOfRows: Int
    let numberOfColumns: Int

    init(colonySize: Int) {
        self.numberOfRows = colonySize
        self.numberOfColumns = colonySize
    }

    func setCellAlive(xCoor: Int, yCoor: Int) {
        aliveCells.insert(Cell(x: xCoor, y: yCoor))
    }
    func setCellDead(xCoor:Int, yCoor: Int) {
        aliveCells.remove(Cell(x: xCoor, y: yCoor))
    }
    func resetColony() {
        aliveCells.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
    }
    var description: String {
        var desc = ""
        for i in 0..<numberOfRows {
            for e in 0..<numberOfColumns {
                if aliveCells.contains(Cell(x: e, y: i)) { //Usually `x` represents column, and `y` for row
                    desc += "*"
                } else {
                    desc += "-"
                }
            }
            desc += "\n"
        }
        return desc
    }

    //Implement other methods you need
    //...
}
```

As already noted, `Set` is not a good data type for Game of Life. But you **can** implement it using `Set`. Good luck.